# Constructing a vector which entries are related iteratively

Tags: list-manipulation

I'm new to all these stuff, so apologizes if this is so simply to any of you, or if it is already asked (I have been looking for several hours, but didn't succeed in finding something similar).

I have a few hundreds vectors of different length but with ordered entries. 
I want to pick the entries such that, given the first one, the nexts ones are bigger (or equal) than, let's say 3, w.r.t. the previous accepted

```
A = {10, 11, 14, 16, 29};
```

gives

> ```
> {10, 14, 29}
> ```

Comment: Thanks, it does the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just choose **s** and **t** and the starting element **x**

```
F[s_List, t_Integer] := Module[{l, a, x = 1},
l = s[[x]];
a = {};
Quiet@While[l <= Last@s, f = s - l; AppendTo[a, l];
l = Select[f, # >= t &][[1]] + l];
a]   

F[{10, 11, 14, 16, 29}, 3]
```

> {10, 14, 29}

here is a test for t=4 starting from the first position x=1

```
test= Sort@RandomChoice[Range@100, 20]  
F[test,4]
```

> {6,9,14,18,21,30,36,44,44,45,52,70,71,74,82,88,90,92,93,96}
>   {6,14,18,30,36,44,52,70,74,82,88,92,96}

Answer (score 0):

This tiny compiled function should do:

```
cf = Compile[{{a, _Integer, 1}, {d, _Integer}},
   Block[{bag, threshold, buffer},
    buffer = Compile`GetElement[a, 1];
    bag = Internal`Bag[{buffer}];
    threshold = buffer + d;
    Do[
     buffer = Compile`GetElement[a, i];
     If[buffer >= threshold,
      threshold = buffer + d;
      Internal`StuffBag[bag, buffer]
      ];
     , {i, 2, Length[a]}];
    Internal`BagPart[bag, All]
    ],
   CompilationTarget -> "C",
   RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
   Parallelization -> True,
   RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
   ];
```

Usage example:

```
cf[{10, 11, 14, 16, 29}, 3]
```

> {10, 14, 29}

This function is listable, so it can process lists of list quite efficiently:

```
A = Sort /@ RandomInteger[{0, 100}, {100000, 100}];
cf[A, 3]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> 0.035603